# На сайте Wordpress перестал работать customize

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

У меня на сайте WordPress перестал работать customize. Первым же делом я стал отключать плагины и при отключении плагина Yoast SEO, customize заработал. Можно было сказать, что проблема из-за этого плагина, но если его включить и отключить плагин Carbon Fields, то проблема так же решается (начинает работать customize). При отключении остальных плагинов, ничего не меняется. В логах (debug.log) никаких ошибок нет. Но заметил, что в консоли браузера появляется ошибка :
Uncaught TypeError: _.contains is not a function
Если отключить плагин Yoast SEO или Carbon Fields, то проблема решается и ошибка из консоли так же пропадает. Но избавиться от этих двух плагинов я не могу, т.к. весь сайт на них строится.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема ? Как исправить эту ошибку ?

Comment: Попробуй для начала поставить дефолтнцю тему и убедиться что все ллагины обновлены. А метки php и js тут не причём.

Comment: @SeVlad Все плагины обновлены. На дефолтных темах проблема не пропадает. 

Почему метки  php и js не подходят ? 
Ошибка явно происходит в js

Comment: Если и на дефолтной проблема - проблема мб в браузере. Измени префик в базе и установи ВП по новой, проверь. Потом снесёшь таблицы. По меткам - см их описание. Они для вопросов  по ЯП, а не для подобных. Ты б еще  метку "русский язык" или "таблицы" присандалил. А чо они же тоже "участвуют" в вопросе.

Comment: Можно подробнее что за ошибка?